# How to get original file from Struts Multipart Request Wrapper

Tags: struts2

Can any one please help me how to get the real file name from Struts2 MultiPartRequestWrapper.

```
MultiPartRequestWrapper multiWrapper =
    (MultiPartRequestWrapper) ServletActionContext.getRequest();
Enumeration fileParameterNames = multiWrapper.getFileParameterNames();

if(fileParameterNames.hasMoreElements()){
    String inputValue = (String) fileParameterNames.nextElement();

    File[] files = multiWrapper.getFiles(inputValue);

    for (File cf : files) {
        System.out.println(cf.getParentFile().getName());                   
        System.out.println("cf is : " + cf.getName());
        System.out.println("cf is : " + cf.toURI().getPath());

        File.createTempFile(cf.getName(),"");

    }

}
```

I can see original file name, type, size  from "fileParameterNames" but when get file I can only see tempfile with upload_xxxxxxxxx.tmp.

How can I get original file name from the File.

Advance thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing all that?

See the [file upload FAQ](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-upload-files.html) and [details](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/file-upload.html) pages. All you need to do is provide the appropriate action properties:

```
public void setUploaded(File myDoc);
public void setUploadedContentType(String contentType);
public void setUploadedFileName(String filename);
```

and use the file upload interceptor, which is included in the default stack.

Note that different browsers send different information; some only send the original filename, while some send the complete path.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for quick response. But

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for quick response. I am submitting file though ajax with ajax file upload plugin. With normal servlet and apache fileupload api I am getting files. When I implement same with strut2 i am getting empty file list. Thats why 
I implemented with MultipartRequestWrapper. With this I can see file list but when I am looping through file list I am getting temporary file name but I want real filename. Is it possible. The above solution works if you have one form. But I have to generate dynamic form with fileupload in struts2. Please help.

Comment: @venkatanaveen S2 doesn't know if it's an Ajax request or not; it just sees a request. Something else is different. I don't understand, though; your question says you can see the original filename and the uploaded file name--what are you trying to get? There are `getFileNames`, `getFileParameterNames`, `getFiles`, and `getFileSystemNames`.

Comment: Hi Dave, I want to create temp file with original file name. If you see my first post I am getting files with getFiles method. I am looping through file list. I am getting file but when I do file.getName() it is giving upload_xxxx.tmp file. I know it is wrapper around the file. Enumeration fileParameterNames = multiWrapper.getFileParameterNames(); when I inspect fileParameters I can see original file name, type, size. I wanted to get original file name. Is it possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @venkatanaveen You said you *have* the original file name; I don't understand. Rename the temporary file if you want. Although if someone uploads a document with the same name the older one will disappear--it's generally better to have more-unique filenames.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your response. That's want I wanted to do. I can create file name with some random name. But I want to create file with its original name because I have to show the file on UI. When I do with normal servlet with apache fileupload api I can see file name as Original filename with some random nunmber with .tmp. Ex: suppose if I upload "test.pdf" when I create with tempfile the file name is "test.pdf202010202102.tmp". When I use with multipartrequestwrapper I am getting "upload_xxxxx_xxx.tmp". Here I am loosing real file name. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use : `multiWrapper.getFileNames("file")[0]`

Where "file" is the name of the file control.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', files[i]);
```